# using distance metric in MLpack

Tags: c++11, mlpack

I want to use ML pack distance metrics to evaluate distance.

I have two arma:vec. Need to find distance between the two vec.

`mlpack::metric::EuclideanDistance distance();`

```
cout<<distance.Evaluate(temp_vec2, temp_vec2);
```

Not sure how to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mlpack::metric::EuclideanDistance distance;

instead of

mlpack::metric::EuclideanDistance distance();

works